# How expressing within and between groups variability?

Tags: anova, error-propagation, variability

I have a double question related with expressing the variability (as standard deviation) of a dataset.
Let's say I want to give an average value of the nitrogen content in "fruits" (units: percentage over dry matter). I have the nitrogen content of apples, oranges and bananas.

| apples | oranges | bananas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.15 | 3.15 | 5.15 |
| 1.16 | 3.16 | 5.16 |
| 1.18 | 3.18 | 5.18 |

The within-group variability is the same in all the groups (SD = 0.015). I think that the correct way to express the within-group variability is the average of the SD of every group. This is equivalent to the approach of ANOVA for within-group variation (root square of mean square within groups).

The problem comes when I try to express the between-group variability. I can only think of 3 solutions:

- Calculating the mean for each group and using this 3 data forgetting the intragroup variability (with this approach we obtain a mean: 3.16 and a SD: 2)
- Calculating the mean and SD for each group and using an error propagation method for averages (see link) gives me a value of SD: 0.0088. Clearly, this is not expressing the intergroup variability. (https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/science/biology/simple-error-propagation-formulas-for-simple-expressions-149357/)
- Using the ANOVA approach for between-group variation it gives me the sum of squares of 3*(-2)^2+3*0^2+3*2^2 = 24. Then I divided between the degrees of freedom (2) and then I took the squared root and I obtained SD: 3.46. This value seems too high (where this variability comes from?).

Is valid some of these approaches? Why?